# Php Yii: parameter passing to action vs load model in action

Tags: php, parameters, model, yii

I'm trying to optimize my code, and i can't decide on what to use, and whichever is the best practice.

I have a view say **view1.php**, that is rendered by an action. Now **view1** contains a model **$model** that was passed on to the view by its action; now i'm using the **$model** again to use it in another different action like below:

**view1.php:**

```
$studyDetails = $this->actionStudyDetails($model);
```

and in the StudyDetails action, i'm going to use the $model,

**StudyController.php:**

```
public function actionStudyDetails($model){

//do some processing of the model here and return an object

}
```

My question is, is it a good idea to pass an entire object that's already been loaded, supposing the model is very large? in terms of optimization , or probably best practice?

or should i just pass the id or primary key say $model->id? and then load the model after; making my action like this:

**StudyController.php:**

```
public function actionStudyDetails($id){
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
//do some processing of the model here and return an object

}
```

Should i pass the entire object unto the action or is it best to just reload the model once inside the action? Thanks, i hope i explained it well

Comment: What you describe is just plain impossible: You can't pass an object as URL parameter.

Comment: wait..i know this looks impossible, and in some parts of other modules in the project this doesn't work.. and it's really weird that it works in my example.. i don't know why actually, other wise i wouldn't have put the question here in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I much prefer loading that single row the database. It's an optimization I wouldn't worry about until it becomes an issue.

You can store the model in your controller to prevent running the same query multiple times:

```
// Store model to not repeat query.
private $model;

protected function loadModel( $id = null )
{
    if($this->model===null)
    {
        if($id!==null)
            $this->model=SomeModel::model()->findByPk($id);
    }
    return $this->model;
}
```

It's a trick I learned [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/60/).